# Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. ( from python shell)

Tags: java, python

im using the javaanpr.jar for LICENSE PLATE RECOGNITION

if im run this code `java -jar javaanpr.jar -recognize -i test.jpg` 
its works , but if i want to run it from a python file   ( let it run after a button press )  if gives me a error  Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN)

a  = True
while True:
    input_state = GPIO.input(23)
    if input_state == True:
      os.system("sudo java -jar -recognize -i javaanpr.jar test010.jpg /home/pi/javaanpr/javaanpr/dist/javaanpr.jar")
```

Comment: Don’t use `os.system`. Use `subprocess.run`.

Comment: if i run this  it says   """ ImportError: No module named 'RPi'"""